# How to Play live streaming of youtube video with Server URL and Stream Key

Tags: ios, objective-c, youtube, live-streaming

I am working on an app in which i have to display the `live streaming` of `youtube` videos. for this i have Server key and `server URL`. I tried to use AVPlayer but not working Please anyone suggest any way to how to implement it as i already gone through many questions but unfortunately didn't find any solution for it.

```
Server URL rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2 
Stream name/key 41wu-5jzt-8sak-7xwe
```

i am using the following code:

```
NSURL *streamURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"*********"];

    _streamPlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:streamURL];

    [self.streamPlayer.view setFrame: self.view.bounds];

    self.streamPlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleEmbedded;

    [self.view addSubview: self.streamPlayer.view];

    [self.streamPlayer play];
```

Comment: `MPMoviePlayerController` is deprecated since iOS 9. You should switch to the [`AVKit`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avkit?language=objc). We don't know the `streamURL` value, what if it is wrong? We don't know what _but not working_ exactly means.

Comment: @zrzka i am sharing youtube Api--- Server URL  rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2     Stream name/key  41wu-5jzt-8sak-7xwe
Please help me to resolve it i am stuck on this from days

Answer (score 1):

You can’t play a YouTube RTMP stream like that. RTMP is  only used for contribution on YouTube. Playback must be done like any other YouTube video.  Also iOS cant play RTMP out of the box like that. You would need to write an RTMP client or use a library.

Comment: Please help me how to handle this type of url. please share some code. I am stuck on this from days

Comment: You don't understand. There is no "handling this type of url" the way you think.  You are asking how to drive your car to the moon. You can't get to your goal by going down the path you are taking. It doesn't work that way.

Comment: please suggest any other thing what i ask to the client to make live streaming in the app through youtube

Comment: embed the YouTube player.

Answer (score 0):

You can use YouTube data api v3 and get stream url and play in YouTube Player using Player api